# How can I replace text to an image URL in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, text, replace

I want to change the text of a link when it is clicked. I'm using the following code but it is not working for me:

```
<a id="pp" href="#" title="" onclick="playPause()">play</a>
function playPause(){
  if($('.controls li #pp').text() == 'play'){
    inter = setInterval(function() {
      changeBannerImg(num,1);
    }, 4600);
    document.getElementById('pp').innerHTML = 'pause';
  } else if($('.controls li #pp').text() == 'pause'){
    clearInterval(inter);
    document.getElementById('pp').innerHTML = 'play';
  }
}
function stopAni(){
  clearInterval(inter);
  document.getElementById('pp').innerHTML = 'play';
}
```

Comment: This question is almost as unclear as possible!

Comment: Does the code "if($('.controls li #pp').text()" actually obtain the <a> html object? Because "document.getElementById('pp').innerHTML = 'pause';" should work.

Comment: img url       <img src="../imgs/play.png">

Comment: I'm currently voting to close because the question is almost indecipherable. *Please*, take some time to explain what you're doing, what should happen, what's going wrong. Clarify, as precisely as possible, what you need help with. It's important to remember that you *know* what you're doing, but we *don't*. For guidance please consider reading '[Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints/),' by [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

Answer (score 0):

Unclear question - that is true..
Not sure what was meant by second sentance but anyway. Assuming you want to change text to an image, just replace "play" and "pause" text with html image tag linking to your image.

Comment: not working :( 

and i changed it to this code 

    <a id="pp" href="#" title="" onclick="playPause()"><img src="../imgs/play.png"></a>

and in java code replace all word (play) to     <img src="../imgs/play.png"> and not working

Comment: okay thanks , its working when i change this .text() to this .html()